# How to align text in skewed div using CSS?

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

How to align text with tilt div same as image with out script.
Below is my code  effort

Please help.

```css
 body {
    margin:50px;
    min-width:400px;
    background:white;
}

div {
    border-bottom: 180px solid rgb(233, 233, 65);
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    margin-top: 60px;
/*    transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform:rotate(3deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(3deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(3deg);*/
}
div p {
   
    color:#000;
    font-size: 14px;
}

div p span{
    /*transform:skew(1deg);*/
   

}
```

```html
<div><p>Lorem ipsum dolcing elit. Sed ullamcorper mattis risus cursus lobortis. Etiam in erat erat. Morbi venenatis quam enim, elementum bibendum elit sollicitudin mollis. Integer rutrum orci sed cursus cons risus cursus lobortis. Etiam in erat erat. Morbi venenatis quam enim, elementum bibendum elit sollicitudin mollis. Integer rutrum orci sed cursus cons risus cursus lobortis. Etiam in erat erat. Morbi venenatis quam enim, elementum bibendum elit sollicitudin mollis. Integer rutrum orci sed cursus cons risus cursus lobortis. Etiam in erat erat. Morbi venenatis quam enim, elementum bibendum elit sollicitudin mollis. Integer rutrum orci sed cursus cons risus cursus lobortis. Etiam in erat erat. Morbi venenatis quam enim, elementum bibendu cursus cons risus cursus lobortis. Etiam in erat erat. Morbi venenatis quam enim, elementum bibendum elit sollicitudin mollis. Integer rutrum orci sed cursus consectetur. Aliquam vitae consequat augue. Suspendisse pharetra sit amet lacus eget semper. Sed condimentum suscipit faucibus.</p></div>
```

[image]

Comment: @harry see my question and another both are skew (tilt) on different side.

Comment: @Maddy the approach is the same (using `shape-outside` or multiple floated elements) as in the linked question. You can also have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5487983/slanted-text-container which is similar

Comment: thanks for comment but I need with only CSS not SCRIPT.